# One Hot Encoding giving same number for different words in keras

Tags: python-2.7, theano, keras, one-hot-encoding

Why I am getting same results for different words?

```
import keras
keras.__version__
'1.0.0'
import theano 
theano.__version__
'0.8.1'

from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
one_hot('START', 43)
[26]
one_hot('children', 43)
[26]
```

Answer (score 2):

unicity non-guaranteed in one hot encoding

see [one hot keras documentation](http://keras.io/preprocessing/text/)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Keras source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/text.py), you can see that the words are hashed modulo the output dimension (43, in your case):

```
def one_hot(text, n,
        filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n',
        lower=True,
        split=' '):
    seq = text_to_word_sequence(text,
                            filters=filters,
                            lower=lower,
                            split=split)
    return [(abs(hash(w)) % (n - 1) + 1) for w in seq]
```

So it is very likely that there will be a collision.